# What makes up "Queries per second avg" in MySQL

Tags: mysql

When running the `status` command in MySQL, one of the metrics that is sent back is "Queries per second avg: 5910.758"

I was wondering if anybody know what makes up that number?

Reason for asking is we tracked all the selects, updates, inserts from the performance_schema and we don't get anywhere near that number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracing it through it ends up being a COM_STATISTICS in the protocol, resulting in this bit of [server code](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/e4924f36486f971f8a04252e01c803457a2c72f7/sql/sql_parse.cc#L1938).

So based this 'Queries per second avg' is the, the thread_id as the number of queries, divided by the total uptime of the server.

Answer (score 0):

`SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`  You will see `Questions` and `Uptime`.  Divide those to get the avg QPS (since restart).  The status values are (or used to be) in `information_status`.`GLOBAL_STATUS`.  What version of MySQL are you using?

Also note `Com_select`, Com_update`, etc.  They may add up to`Questions`.

`Queries`, I think, includes `Questions`, plus queries that are inside Stored Routines.

5910 is a rather large value.  I would put it above the 95th percentile.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out some more data, related to @danblack and @rickjames above:

```
SELECT EVENT_NAME, COUNT_STAR FROM performance_schema.events_statements_summary_global_by_event_name WHERE EVENT_NAME LIKE 'statement/sql/%' and COUNT_STAR > 0 order by COUNT_STAR;
```

This shows all the counts.

Summing this all gives a value, say 7 billion - dividing that by the uptime seconds, gets you to the correct answer (close any ways) to what the "status" command gives.